# images looks blurry when adding it to xcode with three sizes

Tags: ios, xcode

when adding images in Xcode with the three sizes (1x,2x,3x),

and after that adding it to the storyboard,

the image will look blurry and unclear.

Size example

```
1x = 8X8
2x = 15X15
3x = 22X22
```

[image]

Second issue the image looks very small (like the menu icon in the image below) in case it was in the three size 1x,2x,3x,

but if i added only 3x it will be ok like the search icon

[image]

Comment: what is the size of image, where you placing this image in storyboard? can you post screenshot

Comment: If your base (1x) image is 8x8, then your others _must_ be 16x16 and 24x24

Comment: What is the size of your `imageView` or `button`? It is looking larger than the `image` size. Giving the @3x to 22x22 is not correct but also this is not the reason for blurry picture in your case. Try checking the size of `imageView` and `image` both should be same or set the property of `imageView` as `aspectFit`.

Comment: The image is in aspectfit mode, but whenever i add an image with the three sizes, it will show blurry.
but if i added only one size it will look ok.

Answer (score 1):

Check the actual size of the image. Just naming them with @2x and @3x won't increase its size.

Example:

```
1x = 100x50
2x = 200x100
3x = 300x150
```

Answer (score 1):

A trivial suggestion: if you're not working with vectorial stuff, start from the highest resolution you have and then downgrade it to avoid loss of definition.

I mean: start from 24x24, save it @3x and then resize it to 16x16, saving the @2x version. do the same with 8x8.